# Google api key Authorized JavaScript Origins doesnt work with subdomains

Tags: google-api

When creating a new web application in Google for Google 'login', there is an input 'Authorized JavaScript Origins' where you have to enter your urls.

It works with domains and subdomains, if I enter it manually. However I need to enter a wildcard, but http://*.example.com doesnt work.

Is there a way to use a wildcard and make subdomains work for API keys? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar issue. As far as I know, it isn't possible:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/oauth2-dev/sj5jeksUV4M